# Overriding backbone model prototype vs extending model

Tags: validation, backbone.js, prototype

I'm new to Backbone.js and in my recent project I need a custom validation mechanism for models. I see two ways I could do that.

1. Extending the Backbone.Model.prototype

   _.extend(Backbone.Model.prototype, {
        ...
     });
2. Creating custom model that inherit from Backbone model

   MyApp.Model = Backbone.Model.extend({ ... });

I quite unsure which one is a good approach in this case. I'm aware that overriding prototype is not good for native objects but will that applies to backbone model prototype as well? What kind of problems I'll face if I go with the first approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to use the second approach, that's the whole point of Backbone.Model.extend({}).

It already does your first approach + other near tricks to actually setup a proper inheritance chain (_.extend is only doing a copy of the object properties, you can look up the difference in code for Backbone's extend() and Underscore's _.extend, they are very large and not very interesting. Just extending the .prototype isn't enough for 'real' inheritance).

When I first read your question, I misunderstood and thought you were asking whether to extend from your own Model Class or directly extend from Backbone Extend. It's not your question, so I apologize for the first answer, and just to keep a summary here: you can use both approach. Most large websites I saw or worked on first extend from Backbone.Model to create a generic MyApp.Model (which is why I got confused, that's usually the name they give to it :)), which is meant to REPLACE the Backbone.Model. Then for each model (for instance User, Product, Comment, whatever..), they'll extend from this MyApp.Model and not from Backbone.Model. This way, they can modify some global Backbone behavior (for all their Models) without changing Backbone's code.

Comment: What pain I'll face if I use the first approach?

Comment: Thanks, still I haven't got the answer for this question "What kind of problems I'll face if I go with the first approach?"

Comment: It's a complicated question, did you look at the code as I suggested? You'll see in the code that for instance, using Backbone.Model.extend() will give you a __super__ property to access the parent's prototype. But the most important key feature is that it gives you surrogate inheritance out of the box. So, going by the first approach, you will face all the problems that surrogate inheritance tries to solve, for instance, not calling the parent's constructor when you don't need it...

Comment: I'm unaccepting this as answer to bring more people in the discussion and to throw a bounty.

Comment: Ok... maybe give some idea of what kind of information you need? _.extend does a "Copy all of the properties in the source objects over to the destination object" (from the documentation) and .extend() does "[...] set up the prototype chain, for subclasses. Similar to goog.inherits, but uses a hash of prototype properties and class properties to be extended.". So to me, it's pretty obvious why you should do .extend() and not _.extend()! One is meant for basic objects, one is specifically meant for inheritance.

Comment: I narrowed down the question to "Mixins vs inheritance for extending backbone models". At what time I can go for mixin (which is the first approach) and inheritance?

Comment: Technically, they are very similar (once again, .extend() USES _.extend() so you aren't comparing two approaches!). The main difference is the concept of the prototype chain: when you do _.extend, you COPY (the uppercase is for emphasis, not shouting) the properties, so updating the parent class's method after the _.extend will not benefit to the child. Also, probably not much of an issue, but the overall memory footprint would be bigger (again, copy vs prototype chain...). So in most cases, there are no practical differences... but there is no reason to not use .extend().

Answer (score 1):

`_.extend(Backbone.Model.prototype,  {...mystuff...})` would add your property/ies to *every* Backbone.Model, and objects based on it. You might have meant to do the opposite, `_.extend({...mystuff...}, Backbone.Model)` which won't change Backbone itself.

If you look at the [annotated Backbone source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html) you'll see lines like

```
_.extend(Collection.prototype, Events, { ... Collection functions ...} )
```

This adds the Events object contents to every Collection, along with some other collection functions. Similarly, every Model has Events:

```
 _.extend(Model.prototype, Events, { ... Model functions ...})
```

This seems to be a common pattern of making "classes" in Javascript:

```
function MyClass(args) {
  //Do stuff
}

MyClass.prototype = {....}
```

It's even used in the Firefox source code.